# Why is 'mum' the word?

Tags: etymology, idioms

There's an English (probably specifically British) idiom:

> Mum's the word

It basically means that something is secret, and not to talk about it. It can variously mean:

- I won't talk about this.
- Don't talk about this.
- Hide this thing.
- Lie about this subject if you have to.

There are phrases derived from it, such as 'to keep mum'.

Also, 'mum' is a British shortening of 'mother'.

So, why is 'mum' synonymous with secrecy? What are the origins of the phrase?

Comment: [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/mums-the-word.html) is a general reference.

Comment: I've never knowingly heard this idiom used with the sense of *Lie about this subject if you have to*. So far as I'm concerned, it always means *I / you / we **mustn't talk about it at all*** (truthfully or otherwise, and regardless of whether the subject matter is "secret"). It's entirely coincidental that ***mum*** also happens to be a BrE shortening of ***mother***.

Answer (score 1):

It refers to the interjection ***[mum](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mum-s-the-word)*** meaning an inarticulate closed-mouth sound.

***Mum's the word***:

> - Please keep quiet; don't say anything (1704+)

(The Dictionary of American Slang)

> - "be silent," 1560s, ***from Middle English mum, mom (late 14c.), inarticulate closed-mouth sound***, indicative of unwillingness or inability to speak.
> - ***As an adjective meaning "secret" from 1520s. Phrase mum's the word is first recorded 1704***.

(Etymonline)

Comment: And these expressions long pre-date the use of 'Mum'; as a pet name for one's mother, though I believe there was a WWII slogan 'Be like Dad, keep Mum' which punned on it.